# getPalindromes using filter

Tags: javascript

can anyone help me return a palindrome using the filter function. i can do it using a FOR LOOP but struggling with the filter function.

This is the question:

**function getPalindromes(words)** {
  /*
    This function takes an array of words and returns an array containing only the palindromes.
    A palindrome is a word that is spelled the same way backwards.
    E.g. ['foo', 'racecar', 'pineapple', 'porcupine', 'tacocat'] =>  ['racecar', 'tacocat']
  */ }

and this is the answer that i have:

*return words.filter( word => word.split(" ").reverse().join(''))*

and im getting this back:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let arr = ['foo', 'racecar', 'pineapple', 'porcupine', 'tacocat']

let palindromes = arr.filter(word => word.split('').reverse().join('') === word)

console.log(palindromes)
```

In this code you are filtering each `word` in the `arr`, splitting the `word` into an array of characters, reversing their order, and joining the characters back together into a string. Finally, you compare it to the original `word`.

Comment: i swear i tried that.....yes thats worked. thanks for your help.

Comment: @James Glad it worked! Please, consider accepting my answer. Take care